# How to create new dataframe rows based on df value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe which is something like this:

```
index buyedA total
a      2    4
b      1    2
```

and I need to turn it into something like this:

```
index buyedA total
a      1    1
a      1    1
a      0    1
a      0    1
b      1    1
b      0    1
```

I need for each *index* as many **rows** as specified by column *total* (each one filled with a value of 1), and if column *buyedA* says 2, I need 2 of those rows filled with a 1.

Is there a way to do so in Python?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Using `repeat` and a simple `groupby`

```
n = df.loc[df.index.repeat(df.total)].assign(total=1)
n['buyedA'] = n.groupby('index').total.cumsum().le(n.buyedA).astype(int)
```

---

```
  index  buyedA  total
0     a       1      1
0     a       1      1
0     a       0      1
0     a       0      1
1     b       1      1
1     b       0      1
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's try this:

```
#make sure index is in the dataframe index
df=df.set_index('index')

#use repeat and reindex
df_out = df.reindex(df.index.repeat(df['total'])).assign(total=1)

#Limit buyedA by row number in each group of index
df_out['buyedA'] = ((df_out.groupby('index').cumcount() + 1) <= df_out['buyedA']).mul(1)

df_out
```

output:

```
       buyedA  total
index               
a           1      1
a           1      1
a           0      1
a           0      1
b           1      1
b           0      1
```